# How does a browser know if a site supports HTTP/2?

Tags: http2

If I type out https://http2.golang.org/ the chrome browser will automatically send the HTTP/2 request. How is this done?

Comment: in the RFC there's quite a good explanation how this works: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-3.2

Answer (score 46):

Take stackoverflow for example, when the browser sends a request to `stackoverflow.com`, it has to do the following steps:

1. DNS lookup. find the ip address of stackoverflow.
2. TCP/IP handshake
3. TLS handshake.
4. HTTP request/response (Application Protocol).
5. ....

## TLS handshake

Regarding step3 TLS handshake, there is an [nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500050/what-if-an-http-1-1-client-talk-to-an-http-2-only-server-and-what-if-an-http-2-c) by @Oleg.

In order to inspect the detail of TCP/IP packet, You may need use some tools to capture packets. e.g.  [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

### Client sends `ClientHello` to server, which carries several things

- supported cipher suite. which cipher suites do you like?
- supported TLS version.
- a random number.
- **the supported Application Protocols. e.g. HTTP/2, HTTP 1.1/ Spdy/..**
- ...

[image: Client Hello]

### Server responds `SeverHello`, which carries

- chosen cipher suite.
- chosen TLS version.
- a random generated number
- And, chosen application protocols in [TLS application-layer protocol negotiation (ALPN)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301), e.g. `HTTP/2`

[image]

### Conclusion

HTTP2 request/response happens in step4. Before that, browser has already know whether sever support HTTP/2 through TLS handshake.

Answer (score 6):

The chrome browser will only send a HTTP/1.1 Request to the website. As the website is HTTP/2 Enabled, it will send a message to the browser that it supports HTTP/2. The server upgrades the communication protocol between it and the server to HTTP/2 if it finds the browser capable of recognizing HTTP/2. 
So, it is generally the server which converts a request to the HTTP/2 Connection. The browser just complies with the upgrade policy of the server.
The chrome browser displays that you have a HTTP/2 connection with the server or website, only after the server upgrades the communication protocol.

Answer (score 2):

> The string "h2" identifies the protocol where HTTP/2 uses Transport Layer >Security (TLS) [TLS12]. 
>   This identifier is used in the TLS application-layer protocol negotiation (ALPN) >extension [TLS-ALPN] field and in any place where HTTP/2 over TLS is identified.

If server support http2.0 browser will find that server is support http2.0 in TLS application-layer protocol negotiation.
[refer link](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#versioning)!