# require("http2") in angular 7

Tags: angular, http2

I want to use http2 for client side in my angular project.

```
const http2 = require("http2");
const client = http2.connect("http://localhost:8443");

const req = client.request({
    ":path": "/"
});
```

When I wrote this code block for http2 request, I get error ***Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/path' .***

There was http2 package ("npm install http2" command), but this package showing "This package has been deprecated" and "Use the built-in module in node 9.0.0 or newer, instead". Thus, I cannot use this package.

Thus, I cannot get data from server using http2 client like nodejs. How can I fix these problem?

- Node version: v13.3.0
- npm version: 6.13.1
- @angular/cli: "~7.3.7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the built in [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) to get the data from server.

1- Make service and import httpclient in your service like below.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

getData() {
    return this.http.get(serverUrl, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    });
}
```

2- import service in your component. [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) //fetcher

```
import { FetcherService } from 'relative path';
// inject it in constructor
constructor(public fetcherService: FetcherService) {}
```

3- subscribe [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) observable to you component.

```
saveUpdatedGeojson() {
    this.fetcherService.getData().subscribe((response: any) => {
       console.log(response)
    }, error => {
       console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have another question. When I write the code as above, if the server part accepts only http2, will there be a response return? Or should the server part take http and convert it to http2?

Comment: This might be helpful [http1.1 and http2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500050/what-if-an-http-1-1-client-talk-to-an-http-2-only-server-and-what-if-an-http-2-c)

Comment: is the above link helpfull?